# "Undefined Variable" when trying to echo an array fetched via mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Below is my code:

```
session_start();
include_once "config.inc.php";
$tbl_name="members";

 $username=$_SESSION['username'];
$sql = "SELECT quiz1mark, quiz2mark, quiz3mark FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Then, further down the page:

```
<p><?php echo $data; ?></p>
```

This generates a notice: `Notice: Undefined variable: data in F:\xampp\htdocs\quiz_home.php on line 35`

I've clearly defined the variable though, and am unsure as to what's causing this problem.

```
***Contents of config.inc.php***:

$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";   //the default installation of xampp does not include a mysql password
$db_name="bda";
//connect to the database using the above information (variables)
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect to server");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select database");
```

Comment: We might need to see more code

Comment: $tbl_name isn't a user submitted value, is it? Or $username?

Comment: Lines 1-36 would be a good place to start from.

Comment: Chucked everything there; must of the other stuff between 1 and 36 is just commenting relating to stuff like to-do lists and dating.

Comment: Are you unset()'ing $data between the mysql_fetch_array and the echo? For example, looping over $data then resetting in mid-loop?

Comment: `$data` *would* be an array, you can't just `echo()` it.

Comment: No, not unset()'ing anything at all. That's all the PHP code I've got on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the result when you try?:

```
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: data in F:\xampp\htdocs\quiz_home.php on line 35 NULL` - just throws a NULL onto the end of what I was already getting :/

Comment: Just a test, try var_dump($query); Maybe $query is false then some unexpected behavior may be occurring after that.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: query in F:\xampp\htdocs\quiz_home.php on line 36
NULL` That doesn't work either :S

Comment: So, if there is something between the lines $data = mysql_fetch_array ($query, MYSQL_ASSOC) and <p><?php echo $ data;?></p> show us. Then try putting <p><?php echo $ data;?></p> after $data = mysql_fetch_array ($ query, MYSQL_ASSOC)

Comment: Ended up fixing it strangely, just by merging all the code before <p>echo $data</p> into one <?php ~~ ?> block.